# Decompile Source to Symbol File disabled

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I am using VS 2022 (17.3.3) to debug a binary that has the symbols loaded.  I would like to load up the disassembly, but the option `Decompile Source To Symbol File` is disabled.  Does anyone know why it is not available/

Comment: I found a way to decompile if you open VS without code. Then when you debug, In Solution Explorer, you will see an External Sources section. Under there you can see all the DLLs. You can then right click on a DLL and the Decompile Source To Symbol File will appear.  I was able to then debug with the source files generated.

Comment: But why is it greyed out in the modules window??

Comment: In my case, I don't see `Decompile Source To Symbol File` option at all after using it one time.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that, at least in my case, the debugged application has to be in break mode for the menu item to be enabled.